# Rank of Idempotent Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Give $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A^2=A$, Then Prove that $rank(A)=Tr(A)$

My try:

I took two cases:

Case $1.$ If $A$ is Invertible then we have the only idempotent matrix as $A=I$

$$Rank(I)=n=Tr(I)$$

Case $2.$ If $A$ is Non invertible Then

$Rank(A) \lt n$

But now how to prove it is Trace?